# Install laravel with multiple php versions

Tags: laravel

I have two php version-7.0.3 and 7.2.12. I want to keep both on my system. When i am installing laravel with command "composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog" it always picks php version 7.0.3, how can i force it to use version-7.2.12 and install laravel  5.7.*?

Comment: it requires different xampp or php versions as given on 

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html so just download and install different version you want

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: Linux(Ubuntu 16.04) with nginx

Answer (score 0):

Use the php binary directly to run the composer command.

```
/usr/bin/php7.2 /usr/local/bin/composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

The paths to the php and composer binaries might be different for you, make sure to check these first.

Comment: i am getting error :
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'Composer/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php7212/lib/php') in /usr/bin/composer on line 8

Answer (score 0):

First install needed php versions
eg- 7.4 and 7.1 install both

then

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php

 Selection    Path                  Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/php.default   100       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php.default   100       manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/php7.1        71        manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/php7.4        74        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/php8.0        80        manual mode
```

the switch to number what do you need.. example

4 then click enter